# Why do differant domains have differant prices?

Tags: domains, pricing

Why are `.com` domains cheaper than less common domains? I was recently looking at getting a `.mu` domain, and was surprised that the "cheapest" price I could find was $58 (less if gotten for more years), yet you can get `.com` domains for under $10.

I understand some are country codes, so that might be a factor, but I'm mostly inquiring on why non-county code domains have varying costs (although why costs for country code domains are so much more would be helpful as well).

**Edit:** I am not asking about the difference in prices between registrars, but rather between different domains (`.co`, `.com`, `.tv`, etc). Aka, what is the reason one domain is worth more than another?

Comment: You could say "Why is one can of Coke one price in one shop and a different in another?" ... same thing really different registrars put a different mark up on their domains

Comment: @VincePettit I'm not asking about prices between registrars, I'm asking about the difference in prices between domains.